How to do `float` <-> `double` conversions within libgccjit?
I asked the question on the mailing list but got no answer.
gcc_jit_context_new_cast does not perform float <-> double conversions, although it does not complain about them. I am guessing my only option is to write the conversion functions (in C), link with that code and import the functions from gccjit, but that's cumbersome. Does anyone familiar with libgccjit have any ideas, or is willing to confirm I need to write the functions in C separately?

The float -> double cast seems to work for me with libgccjit. What makes you think it doesn't work?
